# How to Sort data according to Order by clause using DESC order in dapper extensions?

Tags: sorting, c#-4.0, dapper, dapper-extensions

I want to sort data in DESC order. This is my code:

```
var predicate = Predicates.Sort<myPoco>(x => x.name, false);
var result = GetList<myPoco>(predicate).ToList();

protected IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(object predicate, IList<ISort> sort = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, bool buffered = false) where T : class
{
    var result = connection.GetList<T>(predicate, sort, transaction, commandTimeout, buffered);
    return 
}
```

Using Dapper Extensions, I am unable to sort data. The code above throws the following error:

> PropertyName was not found for...

I am mapping `myPoco` property using Dapper Extension's `ClassMapper`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort data using `ISort` in Dapper Extension's.

```
List<ISort> sortList = new List<ISort>();
sortList.Add(Predicates.Sort<myPoco>(x => x.Name, false));

var result = GetList<myPoco>(null, sortList).ToList();
 return result;

    protected IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(object predicate, IList<ISort> sort = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, bool buffered = false) where T : class
     {
                    var result = connection.GetList<T>(predicate, sort, transaction, commandTimeout, buffered);
                    return result;
     }
```